# Regex multiple matches in array

Tags: c#, regex

I have this problem with Regex in C#, where I can't return multiple matches in one array. I've tried using a loop to do it, but I feel there has to be a better way. In PHP, I usually just have to do:

```
<?php

 $text = "www.test.com/?site=www.test2.com";
 preg_match_all("#www.(.*?).com#", $text, $results);

 print_r($results);

 ?>
```

Which will return:

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => Array
         (
             [0] => www.test.com
             [1] => www.test2.com
         )

     [1] => Array
         (
             [0] => test
             [1] => test2
         )

 )
```

However, for some reason, my C# code only finds the first result (test). Here is my code:

```
 string regex = "www.test.com/?site=www.test2.com";
 Match match = Regex.Match(regex, @"www.(.*?).com");

 MessageBox.Show(match.Groups[0].Value);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`Regex.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `Match` which returns a `MatchCollection`, if you want to find all `Matches`.

For example:

```
string regex = "www.test.com/?site=www.test2.com";
var matches = Regex.Matches(regex, @"www.(.*?).com");
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Will produce this output:

```
// www.test.com
// www.test2.com
```

If you want to store all matches into an `Array` you can use `LINQ`:

```
var matches =  matches.OfType<Match>()
              .Select(x => x.Value)
              .ToArray();
```

To grab your values (`test` and `test2`) you need [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var values =  matches.SelectMany(x => Regex.Split(x, @"www.(.*?).com"))
             .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
             .ToArray();
```

Then values will contain `test` and `test2`

Comment: Thank you, but how can I access each of these matches separately? Also, how can I grab just "test" and "test2", like I did with match?

Comment: @user2879373 I have updated my answer.But I think `test` itself doesn't match with your pattern.does it?

Comment: It should be grabbing test from www.test.com and test2 from www.test2.com.

Comment: @user2879373 I understand, you need Regex.Split for that see my update again