# Regex get single, connected number

Tags: c#, regex, split

I am trying to filter out the addressnumber of on inputstring, but the problem is my code yet leads to unwanted results when a string with multiple numbers comes in.

Is there a possibility to tell the Regex to filter into an array or something like that to recognize if there was more than one number in the original string?

```
String theNumbers = String.Join(String.Empty, Regex.Matches(inputString, @"\d+").OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value));
```

I tried it on a different way now aswell, but Regex.Split generates empty Strings in the Array and just filtering them out seems a bit hacky to me.

```
String[] extractedNumbersArray = Regex.Split(inputString, @"\D+");
```

Comment: Could you please show the data you are working an, as well as your desired results?

Comment: You already extract the numbers using `Regex.Matches(inputString, @"\d+").OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value)`. Add `.ToList()` to get the list or `.ToArray()` to get an array. `String.Join` here concats all the found numbers. Try `string[] extractedNumbersArray = Regex.Matches(inputString, @"\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();`

Comment: You're right @WiktorStribiżew this solved my problem :) thanks

Comment: Dupe of [Regex multiple matches in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027715/regex-multiple-matches-in-array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps ([online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kc8JUl)):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var inputString = "1 2 3";

        var values = Regex
            .Matches(inputString, @"(?<nr>\d+)")
            .OfType<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Groups["nr"].Value)
            .ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine("Multipe numbers: " + (values.Length > 1 ? "yep" : "nope"));
        foreach (var v in values) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v);
        }
    }
}
```